# SQL Server sum y distinct - Sumar una vez con registros repetidos

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

Tengo esta tabla de gastos y necesito sumar la columna Total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la tabla tiene en cuenta los productos, y al realizar el sum me suma varias veces el total de una nota (porque en una misma nota había varios productos). Lo que quiero es sumar el total pero únicamente una vez por nota. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Por ejemplo:
Esta es una muestra de la tabla. Como se observa, la nota 32097 aparece dos veces, ya que en una nota hay dos productos.  La columna total que aparece es la columna Total por nota, por eso requiero un distinct a nota y luego un sum a total.

> Es decir, necesito sumar únicamente una vez por nota.

La consulta que tengo hasta ahora

```
select sum(Total)
from Gastos                   
where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31' and 
NombrePartida like '%activo%'
```

Comment: Pasa una muestra de los datos para que entendamos cómo se divide el campo nota.

Comment: Por cierto, si son personales cambia los nombres!! ;)

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz ya quedo aver si me entiendes?

Comment: ok!! Mucho mejor!! dame un par de minutos!!

Comment: Algo así? `select idGasto, FechaGasto, Nota, NombrePartida, sum(Total) from Gastos where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31' and NombrePartida like '%activo%' group by idGasto, FechaGasto, Nota, NombrePartida`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPCION 1: anidar la query en una subtabla con [DISTINCT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187831(v=sql.105))**

*Se supone que sólo tienes un precio por nota, y que por tanto, sólo se generará una repetición por nota.*

```
select SUM(subtabla.Total) from 
(select DISTINCT nota, Total
where FechaGasto >='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31' and 
NombrePartida like '%activo%') as subtabla
```

**OPCION 2: utilizar la función [GROUP BY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) combinada con [MAX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) o [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187831(v=sql.105))**

> `Group by` es una función que agrupará los resultados por el campo que
>   le sugieras. La potencia de estas funciones se aprovecha porque
>   además, los campos sumatorios como SUM, realizan la agregación
>   en base al campo del `GROUP BY`.
>
> Si además tienes me cuenta que `MAX` te dará el valor máximo de una de las notas, únicamente te sacará una por línea, y no las dos ocurrencias.

```
select nota, MAX(Total) as Total into #agrupada
from Gastos                   
where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31' and 
NombrePartida like '%activo%' 
GROUP BY nota
```

Aquí ya tendrás la tabla temporal `#agrupada` sólo con los max por nota, es decir una línea por nota.

Así que consultas la tabla temporal ahora, y verás el total

```
   select sum(Total) from #agrupada
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo también anidando la tabla en el from, como en la opción inicial.

Suponiendo que para cada nota siempre tendrás el mismo "Total". también puedes hacer (en dos pasos, con tabla temporal)

```
select DISTINCT Nota, Total into #agrupada
from Gastos                   
where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31' and 
NombrePartida like '%activo%' 
GROUP BY nota 

select sum(Total) from #agrupada
```

**OPCION QUE CALCULA EL IVA EN FUNCION DEL CAMPO IVA**

> Atendiendo al comentario, se genera la siguiente consulta tambien

```
select sum(Total)
from ( 
  SELECT distinct nota,
  CASE
   WHEN iva = 1 THEN totalxproducto * 1.16    
   WHEN iva = 0 THEN totalxproducto
  END as Total
  from Gastos                   
  where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31
  and NombrePartida like '%activo%' 
 )
```

**Opción Más optimizada** (no le hace falta eliminar duplicados)

```
  SELECT SUM(CASE
        WHEN iva = 1 THEN totalxproducto * 1.16   
        WHEN iva = 0 THEN totalxproducto
        END)
  from Gastos                   
  where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31
  and NombrePartida like '%activo%'
```

Algunos links:

https://programacion.net/articulo/tablas_temporales_en_el_sql_server_281

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190750(v=sql.105)

Comment: ya lo hize asi y me hace el sum para cada nota, lo que quiero es que me sume un total por nota y no que me sume todos los totales por nota, no se si me entiendas.?

Comment: Vamos, que únicamente sume una ocurrencia si la nota se repite, no?

Comment: Por ejemplo que de cada nota diferente me tome un total, y me sume todos esos totales uno por nota y me saque un total unico.

Comment: Asi es Alejandro que solo me tome un total por nota. Y me realiza de todos esos totales y que solo me muestre un resultado.

Comment: ya te lo dejé corregido!! échale un vistazo y ya me contarás

Comment: Ya lo realize con tu recomendacion pero no me deja, esque hay un reporte que me imprime el total que requiero, con crystal reports, con tu respuesta se pasa con $5 mil y no entiendo por que!

Comment: Como??? con qué respuesta exactamente se pasa???  con el max? con el distinct? (cuéntame, que lo mismo hay alguna inconsistencia de datos o hay algo mal)!!

Comment: Con los dos, se pasa, tiene otro campo la tabla que se llama iva, cuando imprime el reporte lo que hace es que el totalxproducto lo suma, pero antes de eso los que tienen iva, los multiplica por 1.16 y luego realiza el sum, el tipo de dato de iva es bit, 0 u 1, cuando es 1 multiplica el precio del producto por 1.16

Comment: Pero ..... A ver, entonces el mío debería dar un valor "Menor" porque no lo multiplica... no?

Comment: ya lo cheque, esque hay una nota que el total, lo tiene mal, no entiendo, si da menos disculpa, entonces como podria realizar la consulta que me tome el campo de totalxproducto, y que si tiene iva en 1 me lo multiplique por 1.16 y luego me realize el sum. Estoy realizando un proyecto y yo no cree esas tablas, por lo cual se me dificulta un poco.

Comment: Es lo que tenía pinta. En estos casos, lo mejor es que cuando llegas a un punto en el que "no sabes por qué", repases todas las afirmaciones que has dado por ciertas una por una . Como yo digo, **no te fíes ni de tu madre**.

Dias de trabajo reales:

- "Me estoy volviendo loco... he copiado los archivos veinte veces al directorio, y no aparecen" 
- Has comprobado lo más importante, que los estés copiando a ESE Directorio?
- Uy....

Comment: Entonces como podria poner una condicion en mi consulta se podra que me seleccione el campo totalxproducto y si esta con valor 1 el iva me lo multiplique por 1.16 y luego me realize el sum?

Comment: creo que con un `case`, dame un seg

Comment: Mira lo hize asi---- select sum(case when iva='1' then totalXproducto*1.16 end) from Gastos y me hace la suma del totalxproducto ya con la mutiplicacion por 1.16, como agrego a mi misma consulta los campos de iva=0 lo hago por separado y si me funciona, como agrego a este case que me sume igual los que tienen iva=0?

Comment: Ya quedo realize dos consultas y las uni y luego sume los resultados de ambas, alguna solucion sin tanto codigo?

Comment: no has visto la ultima?? "Opcion mas optimizada" 

SELECT SUM(CASE
        WHEN iva = 1 THEN totalxproducto * 1.16   
        WHEN iva = 0 THEN totalxproducto
        END)
  from Gastos                   
  where FechaGasto>='2017-01-01'and FechaGasto<='2017-12-31
  and NombrePartida like '%activo%'

Comment: Si ya quedo muchas gracias.

Comment: :) Me alegro!!! ánimo y suerte!!!

Comment: *** si finalmente fue la solución, por favor márcala como resuelta!!!!